# How to create a multi-column Combobox in JavaFX?

Tags: user-interface, javafx, combobox

I am trying to create a `ComboBox` that displays multiple columns in its dropdown menu.

Here is a screenshot that shows how I want it to look:

[image: MultiColumn ComboBox]

Any suggestions?

The only solution that is in my head is to create a custom container by extending `ComboBox` and customizing it with multiple columns.

But does JavaFX even provide me the option to create a custom UI container?

How do you create a custom UI container and how to use it in FXML?

Comment: You don't need a custom `ComboBox`, just a custom `CellFactory`. You can find several existing questions on StackOverflow about doing that. With a custom `CellFactory`, you can use any `Node` (including entire layouts) for the drop down items.

Comment: You would not, however, be able to define it in FXML.

Comment: @Zephyr Okay, Thanks.
I will take a look at CellFactory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to extend `ComboBox` to create a similar layout. Instead, you just need to provide your own implementation of a `CellFactory`.

By creating a custom `CellFactory`, you can control how the items in your `ComboBox` are displayed by providing your own `Listcell` (the item that is actually selectable in the dropdown menu).

I am certain there are many ways to accomplish this, but for this example, I'm going to use a `GridPane` as the root layout for my `ListCell`.

The complete example below has comments throughout as well:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // List of sample Persons
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        persons.addAll(
                new Person("Maria Anders", "Sales Representative", "Zurich"),
                new Person("Ana Trujillo", "Owner", "Sydney"),
                new Person("Thomas Hardy", "Order Administrator", "Dallas")
        );

        // Create a simple ComboBox of Persons
        ComboBox<Person> cboPersons = new ComboBox<>();
        cboPersons.setItems(persons);

        // We need a StringConverter in order to ensure the selected item is displayed properly
        // For this sample, we only want the Person's name to be displayed
        cboPersons.setConverter(new StringConverter<Person>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Person person) {
                return person.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public Person fromString(String string) {
                 return null;
            }
        });

        // Provide our own CellFactory to control how items are displayed
        cboPersons.setCellFactory(cell -> new ListCell<Person>() {

            // Create our layout here to be reused for each ListCell
            GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
            Label lblName = new Label();
            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            Label lblLocation = new Label();

            // Static block to configure our layout
            {
                // Ensure all our column widths are constant
                gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(
                        new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, 100),
                        new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, 100),
                        new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, 100)
                );

                gridPane.add(lblName, 0, 1);
                gridPane.add(lblTitle, 1, 1);
                gridPane.add(lblLocation, 2, 1);

            }

            // We override the updateItem() method in order to provide our own layout for this Cell's graphicProperty
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Person person, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(person, empty);

                if (!empty && person != null) {

                    // Update our Labels
                    lblName.setText(person.getName());
                    lblTitle.setText(person.getTitle());
                    lblLocation.setText(person.getLocation());

                    // Set this ListCell's graphicProperty to display our GridPane
                    setGraphic(gridPane);
                } else {
                    // Nothing to display here
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        });

        // Add the ComboBox to the scene
        root.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Select Person:"),
                cboPersons
        );

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

// Simple Person class to represent our...Persons
class Person {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty location = new SimpleStringProperty();

    Person(String name, String title, String location) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.title.set(title);
        this.location.set(location);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }

    public StringProperty titleProperty() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location.get();
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location.set(location);
    }

    public StringProperty locationProperty() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

> **The Results:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Thanks, It worked like a charm.
You must be a JavaFX pro :)